# Nhibernate Criteria API

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

```
SELECT O.*, P.* FROM ORDERS O, PRODUCT P WHERE O.ORDER_ID=P.ORDER_ID;
```

What would be the Criteria representation of the above query?

Comment: orders and products are not related with a (.NET) reference?

Answer (score 4):

If you have something like this:

```
public class Order
{
   public virtual ISet<Product> Products {get;set}
}
```

You need to do

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))    
    .SetFetchMode("Products", FetchMode.Eager)    
    .List();
```

That's it.